# How to set Twitter trends in Ukrainian language?

Tags: twitter

I am geographically in Ukraine and I tried to set trends settings "Show content in this location" "Trends for you", but I only see trends in Russian. I do not follow any accounts in Russian, only in English. How to filter out Russian trends?

How my trends look now:
[image: How my trends look now]